# How to change device permissions via udev in RHEL5?

Tags: permissions, device, rhel5, udev

I'm attempting to make the device permissions on a hard drive(/dev/sdb) persistent for a particular group in RHEL5. Can anyone point me to to a proper KERNEL line in /etc/udev/rules that would *work* that attempts the following?

```
KERNEL=="sdb", NAME="%k", GROUP="group", MODE="666", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rule looks good.

Have you put it in a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` before `50-udev.rules`? Then did you reboot or run `/sbin/udevcontrol reload_rules` and then `udevtrigger`?

You can test it like so: `udevtest /block/sdb`

Edit: Here is an example that worked for me. In `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="ttyS0", NAME="%k", GROUP="adm", MODE="666", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Ran `udevcontrol reload_rules` then `udevtrigger --verbose`. Result:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root adm 4, 64 Oct 18 16:16 /dev/ttyS0
```

Test:

```
# udevtest /class/tty/ttyS0
main: looking at device '/class/tty/ttyS0' from subsystem 'tty'
...
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/ttyS0', major = '4', minor = '64', mode = '0666', uid = '0', gid = '4'
```

Edit2: Also you can run `udevcontrol log_priority=debug` to get more info reported via syslog.

Comment: It's been some time since I required this, and I can't quite remember how I solved it. But thanks for the info about udevcontrol.